# Module, that exports another ones

Tags: haskell, import, ghc

Is there a way to create a module that will export other modules?

For example, I have a list of modules: `A`, `B`, `C`. And I want them to be imported to module D.

So, I have to write:

```
import A
import B
import C
```

It works. But may be not very convenient sometimes.

Is there a way to create a `Collection` module that exports the content of `A`, `B` and `C`?

With this feature, instead of previous instructions, I'd only have to write:

```
import Collection -- Importing A, B, C.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use an explicit export list, specifying all functions, types, classes and modules to export from this module.

```
module Foo (module A, module B, myid) where

import A
import B

myid :: a -> a  -- For example
```